# Pivot table sum years

Tags: python, pandas

I created

```
cvv=dd.pivot_table('quantity',index='date',aggfunc=sum)

date   quantity
2012  555
2013  397 
2014  876 
2015  129 
2016  984 
2017    5
```

I'd like to take and sum(quantity) only the last 2 years from the data frame.

Is it easy way to write this?

Comment: `cvv.loc['2015':'2017']`?

Answer (score 1):

We can first perform a filtering, then select the column, and call `sum` on it, like:

```
cvv[cvv['date'] >= 2015]['quantity'].sum()
#   \_________ ________/\_____ ____/ \_ _/
#             v               v        v
#           filter     select column   aggregate
```

Given the `date` column is the index, we can also use `.loc[2015:2017]` to obtain the list rows, and then perform the aggregate over it:

```
cvv.loc[2015:2017]['quantity'].sum()
#   \____ _______/\_____ ____/ \_ _/
#        v              v        v
#      filter   select column   aggregate
```